# Google Analytics regex exclude a phrase

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm creating a content grouping with the following URLs:

```
/my-category/something
/my-category/somethingelse
/my-category/product1-brand-color
/my-category/product2-brand-color
```

How to create a RegEx to group /my-category/ pages but exclude everything that has "brand"?

Comment: what do you mean by pages? Expected output would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Google Analytics doesn't support negative lookahead expressions. Instead, create 2 (or more) filters:

- The first filter to include your regex using the "Only Show" dropdown
- The second filter using the "Don't Show" dropdown containing your exclude rule

Answer (score 0):

More of a GA question than a Regex question. Regex is somewhat fussy to use in Google Analytics. Use GA's 'Advanced filter' option to include and exclude RegEx. You would get your result with either "containing" or "matching Regex" :

Include Page containing category
Exclude Page containg brand

Answer (score -1):

Use a negative look-ahead.

To match `/my-category/` only when it's not followed by `-brand-`

```
/my-category/(?!.*-brand-)
```

Or to match `/my-category/` only when it's not followed by a dash (ie any brand):

```
/my-category/(?!.*-)
```

Comment: I think they want the text after `/my-category/` included too; `/my-category/(?!.*-brand-).+` - cheers!

Comment: I do not think GA supports negative lookahead (at least it hasn't in the past). The solution would rather be to create a content group that includes all brand pages - since pages will go into to group whose rule matches first they will be automatically excluded from the non-brand group that is defined by a later rule.

Comment: Yes, I get this message when I try /my-category/(?!.*-brand-) Your data request includes an invalid regular expression. As I want to use it to define funnel steps and my category pages are before the brand pages this won't work.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want something like this,

```
(?=^\/my-category)(?!.*?brand.*).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tA0sV0/1)

If you wanat this in a group then put open and close parenthesis in the pattern,

```
 (?=^\/my-category)(?!.*?brand.*)(.*)
```