# Excluding a URL With Google Analytics Regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics, regex-negation

I am tracking several urls on my website and I want to count only the ones beginning with /espace-debat

Examples :

```
/espace-debat/debat
/espace-debat/user/random-number
/espace-debat/debats/random-number
```

I am creating a goal on analytics to exclude all the others urls.

I am thinking about this Regex

```
^/(?espace-debat)
```

I don't know how to test it

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41598226/3832970)

Comment: Why you don't test it in the filter field in 'Behavior --> Site content --> All pages' report in Google Analytics?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried escaping your expression?

```
^\/(espace-debat)\/?
```

Comment: No need to escape `/`, it is not a special regex metacharacter and GA regexps are defined with *strings*, not *regex literals* and thus do not need regex delimiters (`/` is a common *regex literal delimiter*).

Comment: ^\(espace-debat)\? isn't working either, it takes into account all the pages, including the one with espace-debat in their url...